Disabling namespace remapping for a container creates sudo permission error
I've enabled default user namespace remapping in Docker. However, I now need to add a privileged container, and therefore need to disable the userns mapping using the --userns=host flag for that new container. Unfortunately, this changes the whole filesystem ownership of my new container to the user I specified in the --userns-remap daemon config.
This produces a series of errors.
When I only set the --userns=host & --privileged flag, I get the following error:
> chmod: changing permissions of '/services/run-docker.sh': 
> Operation not permitted /run-services.sh line 10: /services/run-docker.sh: Permission denied

And when I specify the user as root, I receive the following error response from the container:
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

In the official Docker documentation, this problem is mentioned, but no solution is provided:

...what this means is that the whole container filesystem will belong to the user specified in the --userns-remap daemon config (231072 in the example above). This can lead to unexpected behavior of programs inside the container. For instance sudo (which checks that its binaries belong to user 0) or binaries with a setuid flag.

How can one disable the user namespace remapping for a container and overcome the severe limitation of the new container filesystem ownership?

What are you really trying to do?  You should never need sudo in a container at all, since you can docker run -u root ... to run the single container process as root.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

I'm trying to run a container image, that - unfortunately - uses sudo. Namely: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2024.07.1-linux-sudo. It's a CI/CD build agent that creates a Docker-In-Docker environment.
